# Mist can't run on a testnet?

Tags: blockchain, mist, testnets, bug

When I install Mist, and after a bit of loading, it starts downloading the blockchain for the mainnet, but when I change the network, I get an error that it's not connecting. If I try to restart mist (with the new network which is Ropsten selected), I get this:

[image]

*Question:*

Would anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

To run Mist on the testnet, just select Develop / Network / Testnet.
[image]

I guess the blocks has not yet synced for you. The testnet contains around 1 700 000 blocks againt 2 300 000 for the mainnet. So it will take time.

Comment: Tried this, and it doesn't work. After I do this process is when my mist starts causing the problem above. When I first install MIst, it's on the mainnet and starts downloading the mainnet stuff without issue, but when I do the above is when I get the errors you see in my original post sadly